# (LibGDX/JAVA) How can I get a rectangle to rotate with this pendulum so I can start detecting collisions?

Tags: java, android, collision-detection, libgdx, physics

One of the objects in my game is a pendulum that swings in a semi-circle. This is done by having an update() method like this:

```
public void update() {
    angleAcceleration = +1.81 / length * Math.sin(angle);
    angleVelocity -= angleAcceleration * 0.1;
    angle -= angleVelocity * 0.1;
    // Update the animation and bounds check index
    pendRegIndex = (int) (pendulumRegions.length * ((0 + angle) / (angle * 2)));
    pendRegIndex = pendRegIndex >= pendulumRegions.length ? pendulumRegions.length - 1
            : pendRegIndex;
    pendRegIndex = pendRegIndex < 0 ? 0 : pendRegIndex;
}
```

where pengRegIndex is the index of the texture regions (used by my animator class) and pendulumRegions is the texture regions that bound a full swing of the pendulum. I also write this line in the draw method:

```
    public void draw(SpriteBatch batch) {
    batch.draw(pendulumRegions[pendRegIndex], getxPos() - sprite.getWidth()
            / 2, getyPos(), sprite.getWidth() / 2, 0, sprite.getWidth(),
            sprite.getHeight(), 1, 1,
            (float) (angle * MathUtils.radiansToDegrees));
    }
```

This class extends an abstract class `GameObject` which has a predefined method `getRectangle()` which is usually what I use for collision detection. However, the rectangle that gets drawn when I call the method for the pendulum is it's starting position rather than a rectangle that swings with the pendulum.

How can I test for collisions with this object? The line I use in `draw()` rotates the pendulum but I'm not sure how to rotate a rectangle to follow the same swing. Any ideas?

Grateful for any help.

Comment: How does your `GameObject` class figure out the rectangle?

Comment: sprite.getX(), sprite.getY(), sprite.getWidth(), sprite.getHeight()